# How do I extract the response code from a JSON API request?

Tags: ruby, json, http

Doing this:

```
@resp = Net::HTTP.get_response("api.something.com", "/feed/v1/offers.json?#{@params_api_string}")
```

I get this response in @resp:

```
#<Net::HTTPOK:0x7f451e9d3ef0>
```

How can I extract that OK, or No Content, Bad Request, Unathorized and so on in one variable? Is there some Net::HTTP function to get just that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@resp.message
```

should give you the message.

More methods of the HTTPResponse are available in [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html).